# Search files content for possible BTC key strings

Tags: bash, scripts, find, grep

I have 4 BTC addresses on two of my drives that I cant bloody find. I saved them under stupid name so they would be hard to find if someone had access to my system. Now I cant find them.

Is there a way I can use a script to search for the characteristics of the public key or private key?

This is my public key:

```
1LxpcqQ6a4x1RCjGk838CbMT2HA9qgFq7P
```

Is there a way to write a script that can search my drive looking for the characteristics of this key as well as my private key?

Is there a way to identify it as a BTC private and public key so I can find it?

Comment: Any idea how long your key was? I've a feeling that you are out of luck..

Comment: started with a 5 , 50 i think, or is it 51

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
grep -I -R "1LxpcqQ6a4x1RCjGk838CbMT2HA9qgFq7P" ~
```

Or if you think you might have put it somewhere outside of your home folder replace the ~ with / and see what happens.